# Get Text from ListView Item that was created from DB

Tags: android, listview

i create a ListView with content from a Database.
I want to get the Text from one Item with:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
String item = l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
}
```

But i get some text: "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCurser@45765"

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

What exactly you retrieved from the database. If it's only set of Strings you can try the below code.

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
// Get the item that was clicked
Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
String keyword = o.toString();
Toast.makeText(this, "You selected: " + keyword, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }
```

this should work...

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/widget/AdapterView.java#AdapterView.getItemAtPosition%28int%29 ListView.getItemAtPosition(position) returns exactly the same as ListActivity.getListAdapter().getItem(position) ... in this case it's a Cursor

Answer (score 1):

On **onItemClick** :

```
String text = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
```